# How to use strip in the middle of a string

Tags: python

Given this string, `###hi##python##python###`, how can I remove all instances of `'#'`?

```
v = "###hi#python#python###"
x = v.strip("#")
print(x)
```

Expected output: `"hipythonpython"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is not `strip`, but `replace`:

```
v = '###hi#python#python###'
x = v.replace('#', '') 

print(x)
```

Output:

```
hipythonpython
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use replace

```
the_str = '###hi##python##python###'
clean_str = the_str.replace('#','')
print(clean_str)
```

Output

```
hipythonpython
```